# how to create a vector based on two auxiliary vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I am creating a Matlab program to handle an array of data that contains finite integers (not necessary to be consecutive). Let says my data array is A, I need to find the unique values of A first, that forms a vector B, and I have to count the number of occurrence of each unique value in A, that gives another vector C. Finally, I need a vector E which has the same length of A but with the value of the ith element of E computed as `E(i) = C(k)` with `k = A(i)`

I have the code to create B and C as follows:

```
A=[5 5 1 1 3 1 3 11 9 6 -2];
[B, ia, ic]=unique(A);
C = accumarray(ic,1);
```

A could be a large vector and the elements of A could be very different and in a wide range, I wonder if there is any vectorize approach to generate the array E instead of the following loop method

```
E = zeros(size(A));
for n=1:length(E)
  k=find(B==A(n));
  E(n) = C(k);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say, to calculate the values for `E`, you need to calculate the indices in `B` which correspond to each element in `A`, informally where `A == B`. This obviously won't work because `A` and `B` are different sizes. But we can get what we want by thinking about things as a 2D grid. Transpose one of the vectors and equate them.

```matlab
A == B.'
% or for older versions of MATLAB (won't implicitly expand the different sized variables)
bsxfun(@eq, A, B.')

ans =

  7×11 logical array

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
% to help visualise
% A = [5 5 1 1 3 1 3 11 9 6 -2];
% B = [-2 1 3 5 6 9 11];
```

You can see that, for each column, the position of the 1 tells us the where we can find that element in `A` in vector `B`. We can use `find` to get the row indices of each 1, and use that to calculate E.

```matlab
[indices, ~] = find(A == B.');
E = C(indices);
```

### Final result

If you want to calculate this with one line of code, you can use do the following

```matlab
A=[5 5 1 1 3 1 3 11 9 6 -2];
[B, ia, ic]=unique(A);
C = accumarray(ic,1);
E = C(mod(find(B.' == A)-1, length(B))+1).';
% or for older versions of MATLAB
E = C(mod(find(bsxfun(@eq, A, B.'))-1, length(B))+1).';
```